# Free movement within the EU with EU blue card

Tags: france, eu, blue-card

Does an EU blue card issued by France allow one to live anywhere in the EU or only 90 out of every 180 days? I've heard that those who invest in France, get a 4-year residence permit, and can live anywhere in the EU. But is this true, or am I confusing something?

Answer (score 2):

A **residence permit** issued be a Schengen country allows the holder (together with their passport) to **visit** other Schengen countries based in the 90/180 rule (which is not strictly enforced).

A **EU blue card** is a *residence permit* **type**.

The **passeport talent” “investisseur économique” (Skilled residence permit - Investor)**([International talents/Make a direct economic investment| France-Visas.gouv.fr](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en/web/france-visas/international-talents-and-economic-attractiveness)) may be the other *residence permit* **type** you are referring to.

> and can live anywhere in the EU

This is not mentioned in the above link and is very unlikely.

---

There is one *residence permit* **type** that makes it easier to move from one EU country to another (except Denmark and Ireland, where this permit type is not issued).

In Germany it is called:

- [EU long-term residence permit pursuant to Article 2 (b) of Directive 2003/109/EC](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0118)

Otherwise, in general, a residence permit issued in one Schengen country **does not** allow you to reside and work in another Schengen country.

Comment: I believe that directive 2003/109/EC applies only in the EU, not in other Schengen countries. Regardless, it certainly does not apply in Denmark nor Ireland, which have an explicit opt-out. Also, holders of an EU blue card can acquire permanent residence more easily if they move to another country because they [can add together periods of time spent in different EU countries, instead of the whole five years being in just one EU country](https://ec.europa.eu/immigration/blue-card/essential-information_en). Moving requires a new blue card from the destination country, however.

Comment: @phoog adapted text for EU long-term residence permit.